# How to (easily) split string in Ruby with length and also delimiter

Tags: ruby, string, split

I need to split a string in Ruby which has the following format:

```
 [{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},{a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8},{a:9,b:10,c:11,d:12},{a:13,b:14,c:15,d:16}]
```

ie. it is a generated javascript array. Unfortunately the list is long and I would like to split it up on the array element separator comma after reaching a specific length suitable for editing it with a code editor, but in a way to keep the integrity of the elements. For example, the line above with a split width of 15 would become:

```
 [{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},
 {a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8},
 {a:9,b:10,c:11,d:12},
 {a:13,b:14,c:15,d:16}]
```

and with a width of 32 the text would be:

```
 [{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},{a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8},
 {a:9,b:10,c:11,d:12},{a:13,b:14,c:15,d:16}]
```

Beside of the classical "brute force" approach (loop through, check separator between `}` and `{` while increasing length, split if length greater than and valid separator found) is there a more "Rubyish" solution to the problem?

Edit: Naive approach attached, definitely not Rubyiish as I don't have a very strong Ruby background:

```
def split(what, length)
  result = []
  clength = 0
  flag = FALSE
  what_copy = what.to_s
  what_copy.to_s.each_char do |c|
     clength += 1
     if clength > length
       flag = TRUE
     end

     if  c == '}' and flag
        result << what[0 .. clength]
        what = what[clength+1 .. -1]
        clength = 0
       flag = FALSE
     end
  end
  pp result
  sres = result.join("\n")
  sres
end
```

Comment: Did you write the classical brute force approach?

Comment: @EricDuminil Yes, question updated

Comment: I really don't get where this question is going?  Are you likely to want to split the data contained in {}, ie. would you just have {a:1,b:2}, with obviously adding in the extra brace?  Other wise, if the {} always contain 4 items why not just group them by the braces and return 1, 2, 3 or 4??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a regex with :

- a non-greedy repetition of at least `width-2` characters
- followed by a `}`
- followed by a `,` or a `]`.

---

```
data = "[{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},{a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8},{a:9,b:10,c:11,d:12},{a:13,b:14,c:15,d:16}]"

def split_data_with_min_width(text, width)
  pattern = /
    (                 # capturing group for split
      .{#{width-2},}? # at least width-2 characters, but not more than needed
      \}              # closing curly brace
      [,\]]           # a comma or a closing bracket
    )
    /x                # free spacing mode
  text.split(pattern).reject(&:empty?).join("\n")
end

puts split_data_with_min_width(data, 15)
# [{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},
# {a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8},
# {a:9,b:10,c:11,d:12},
# {a:13,b:14,c:15,d:16},
# {a:17,b:18,c:19,d:20}]

puts split_data_with_min_width(data, 32)
# [{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},{a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8},
# {a:9,b:10,c:11,d:12},{a:13,b:14,c:15,d:16},
# {a:17,b:18,c:19,d:20}]
```

The method uses [`split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) with a capturing group instead of [`scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) because the last part of the string might not be long enough:

```
"abcde".scan(/../)
# ["ab", "cd"]
"abcde".split(/(..)/).reject(&:empty?)
# ["ab", "cd", "e"]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

```
def doit(str, min_size)   
  r = /
      (?:                # begin non-capture group                
        .{#{min_size},}? # match at least min_size characters, non-greedily
        (?=\{)           # match '{' in a positive lookahead
        |                # or
        .+\z             # match one or more characters followed by end of string
      )                  # close non-capture group
      /x                 # free-spacing regex definition mode
  str.scan(r)
end
```

**Examples**

```
str = "[{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},{a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8},{a:9,b:10,c:11,d:12},{a:13,b:14,c:15,d:16}]"

doit(str, 18) # same for all min_size <= 18
  #=> ["[{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},",
  #    "{a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8},",
  #    "{a:9,b:10,c:11,d:12},",
  #    "{a:13,b:14,c:15,d:16}]"] 
doit(str, 19)
  #=> ["[{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},",
  #    "{a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8},{a:9,b:10,c:11,d:12},",
  #    "{a:13,b:14,c:15,d:16}]"]
doit(str, 20)
  #=> ["[{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},{a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8},",
  #    "{a:9,b:10,c:11,d:12},",
  #    "{a:13,b:14,c:15,d:16}]"] 
doit(str, 21)
  #=> ["[{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},{a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8},",
  #    "{a:9,b:10,c:11,d:12},",
  #    "{a:13,b:14,c:15,d:16}]"] 
doit(str, 22) # same for 23 <= min_size <= 37
  #=> ["[{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},{a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8},",
  #    "{a:9,b:10,c:11,d:12},{a:13,b:14,c:15,d:16}]"]
doit(str, 38) # same for 39 <= min_size <= 58
  #=> ["[{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},{a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8},{a:9,b:10,c:11,d:12},",
  #    "{a:13,b:14,c:15,d:16}]"] 
doit(str, 59) # same for min_size > 59
  #=> ["[{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},{a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8},{a:9,b:10,c:11,d:12},{a:13,b:14,c:15,d:16}]"]
```

Comment: Regular expressions FTW! (Though I wouldn't name the method "doit") +1

Comment: Nice. I didn't spend much time trying a `scan` only solution but I didn't find any suitable regex.

Comment: It's also the first time I used `.{32,}?` I wasn't sure it would work, and couldn't find any doc about it.

Comment: @Eric, ditto re `.{32,}?`.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
2.3.1 :007 > a
 => "[{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},{a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8},{a:9,b:10,c:11,d:12},{a:13,b:14,c:15,d:16}]" 
2.3.1 :008 > q =  a.gsub("},", "},\n")
 => "[{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},\n{a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8},\n{a:9,b:10,c:11,d:12},\n{a:13,b:14,c:15,d:16}]" 
2.3.1 :009 > puts q
[{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4},
{a:5,b:6,c:7,d:8},
{a:9,b:10,c:11,d:12},
{a:13,b:14,c:15,d:16}]
 => nil 
2.3.1 :010 >
```

Comment: Not exactly, since if I want the minimum length to be 32, then I would just get 2 lines. Question updated.

Comment: by 32, do you mean the first 32? because the second line exceeds 32.

Comment: Your code is difficult to read because of all the prompts such as `2.3.1 :007: >`. Moreover, if anyone wants to run your code they can't just cut-and-paste. Best to strip out those prompts.